# Is there a way to trigger builds for old commits on circleci/codeship/alternative

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm looking to trigger a build for commits prior to connecting my repository to an online CI platform.  My repository is on github.

Is this possible?

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 0):

CircleCI doesn't work for commits without a ".circleci/config.yml" file.

One way to approach this, is to create a new branch from one commit before you want the build to start, add config.yml file, and rebase your branch on top of it.

Of course, this will create new commits with different hashes.